# The best way to log access to SSRS reports

Tags: audit, ssrs-2008

We have a number of SSRS reports created using BIDS 2008 on SQL Server 2008 r2. The business wants us to log access to these reports. For example who and when run the Report A.

What is the best way of achieving that? Is it suitable if we use SQL Auditing feauture for  that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSRS has Execution Logs for this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155836%28v=sql.100%29.aspx